# Relationship between XOR and "AND"

Tags: logic, computer-science

I want to XOR the password (0x3d), byte by byte, with 0x42, then 0x51, then 0xF7, then 0x6F. this would give me 0xb6..... But, Is there a shortcut to this operation?

Comment: I know there is a shortcut because I saw it before but I forgot how it was??? :)

Comment: Xor is associative : if + denote the xor operation, (a + b) + c = a + (b + c).

Comment: The tags don't fit the question at all.

Comment: Is there a reason why you mentioned AND in the title?

Comment: @FernandoMartin — It was firstly 
“number-theory elementary-number-theory algebraic-number-theory”, and I retagged it as “algebra-precalculus” because it is only symbol manipulation. I'm not sure “logic computer-science” is much better. There should be a tag “elementary-maths”.

Answer (score 1):

XOR is associative. Therefore, denoting XOR by ^, you can do

```
>>> 0x3D ^ 0x42 ^ 0x51 ^ 0xF7 ^ 0x6F
182
```

but also

```
>>> 0x3D ^ (0x42 ^ 0x51 ^ 0xF7 ^ 0x6F)
182
```

which is

```
>>> 0x3D ^ 0x8B
182
```

So you can XOR with 0x8B instead. In other words, "multiple xor" is equivalent to a single one.

Associativity follows because XOR is associative on each bit.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, your answer is not what I am looking for. What I am looking for is that the operation above can be reduced using AND operation. I am looking for how to use AND to shortcut this operation... Thanks

Comment: @jjitti: using AND only, it is impossible, because AND is monotonic while XOR is not. If you want to express XOR with AND and NOT, then use Fernando's answer. Otherwise I don't know what do you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

(p XOR q) = (¬p AND q) OR (p AND ¬q), if that was what you were asking.

Comment: $A \operatorname{xor}{B} = (\lnot A \land B) \lor (A \land \lnot B)$

Comment: Indeed, I mixed them up. Thanks Matt!

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, your answer is not what I am looking for. What I am looking for is that the operation above can be reduced using AND operation. I am looking for how to use AND to shortcut this operation... Thanks